# whats wrong with my uv rendered faces?

Tags: mesh, uv, uv-image-editor

Please help me, im begginer here, mastahh notice me

[image]

Comment: Try this: In edit mode select all, then go to mesh>>normals>>recalculate outside. Try to map the texture again.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like typical Z-fighting. You seem to have doubles (i.e. two faces that are in the same space and overlap)
To remove doubles, go into edit mode, select all faces/vertices, press W and select "remove doubles".

Comment: @nicoblender Don't say "*problem solved*" in the comments, upvote the answer or consider making it as accepted if it solved your problem